# How to close kendo confirm message on close of kendow window?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo window in that I show kendo confirm message. I m closing the kendo window when the confirm message is being shown through singnalR (basically closing the window from backend call). in this case, the window is closed but kendo confirm message does not disappear. Is there any way to close this confirm message.

**Code to close:**

```
var wnd = $("#EditWindow").data("kendoWindow");
wnd.close();
```

**Confirm message:**

```
kendo.confirm("Would you like to proceed?")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not documented well, but kendo.confirm is just a predefined kendo.ui.Dialog : https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/predefined-dialogs and a subclass of Dialog (see https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/6bcf324555451cd638ca0d5e8f152c447860ee7a/src/kendo.dialog.js#L1044 )

You can find the widget the DOM:

```
        kendo.confirm("Are you sure that you want to proceed?");
        setTimeout(function(){                  
            $(document).find('[data-role="confirm"]').data("kendoConfirm").close()
        }, 1000)
```

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/oyAtUKAJ